# How to authenticate in React through AD FS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, adfs, gatsby

I am creating a web app using [GatsbyJS](https://next.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/) that needs to utilize a secured corporate intranet which implements AD FS. I am having difficulty finding a good way to configure this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would use [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) as per this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs).

This [article](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-to-a-cordova-application-64cb9a389e52) may also help as it also references ADAL.js.

Most of the examples leverage Azure AD but they can be ported to work on ADFS.

Answer (score 1):

At today's date, ADAL.js is deprecated. Must use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)

There also is a Microsoft post explaining how to migrate. [Migration post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/msal-migration)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35427401)